# What is supposed to happen when the user says "NO" to the end_session_endpoint?

Tags: openid-connect

In the [OpenID Connect Session (draft 23 at the time of the question)](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html), it states

> At the logout endpoint, the OP SHOULD ask the End-User whether he wants to log out of the OP as well. If the End-User says "yes", then the OP MUST log out the End-User.

So if the user clicks on yes, then we are still in the realm of the OP and we can perhaps bring them back to the welcome screen.  However, if the user clicks on "NO" the behaviour is not defined.

I am guessing that it would be something like:

- let `state` be the last known page that the user was on before pressing the logout button on the RP application.
- the logout of the RP will destroy any credentials that the user has for the RP on the OP using the token revocation endpoint (if reconsent is required by the RP)
- then it will redirect to the end_session_endpoint passing the `state`
- once it gets to the OP end_session_endpoint the user happens to choose "no"
- then the user is not logged out of the OP.
- the user is then redirected back to the post_logout_redirect_uri with the state that has been passed.
- the post_redirect_uri which is on the RP would then redirect the user back to the authentication_endpoint with the state
- since the user is still logged in in the OP and assuming consents were still present it should redirect the user back to the RP callback with the state as if the user hadn't left the application, but with a whole new set of id_token now

To prevent redirect loops, the RP's should ensure that logout does not require valid identity in case one no longer exists.  Otherwise there would be a redirect loop.

Comment: I believe you can implement the proposed flow independently of the OP having to support anything outside of the spec except for that last step. To get a new `id_token` the RP would have to make the user go through a new authentication request flow, where SSO would happen at the OP after some ping-ping redirects.

Comment: I think the `id_token` should be invalidated already when the user logs out from the RP.  Though whether it is "new" or "reused" may be moot but a new `access_token` should still be there though after having the OP go through a new authentication request flow.

Comment: updated to add note to prevent redirect loops